# how to difference between two dates whose Date time type should yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: java, android

i want to get difference between two dates whose input parameter will 
if pass any input date then it should Convert in to  **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**

> Date1 :2016-05-30 20:16:00

---

> Date2: 2016-05-29 20:17:00

```
public long totalHour(Date startDate, Date endDate) {

          int diffInDays = (int) ((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        return diffInDays;
    }
```

I am using this code but unable to get Output in integer form please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

The classical way to calculate the difference between two dates in Java is to:

1. parse them to `Date` objects
2. convert both of them to "milliseconds since the UNIX epoch" by calling `Date.getTime()`
3. subtract one from the other.
4. divide by a constant to convert from milliseconds to the time unit that you require.

Your code seems to be doing that but there are a couple of problems:

1. the constant is wrong
2. you are truncating to an `int` which is liable to give you errors if the two dates are far enough apart.

This would be better:

```
public long hoursDifference(Date start, Date end) {
    return ((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
}
```

Also, you might want to consider rounding rather than truncation.

---

Parsing dates in an arbitrary format is impossible ... unless you know *a priori* what the expected format or formats are.  In that case, you just try the formats, one at a time, until your parse succeeds.  For example, something like this.

```
  SimpleDateFormat[] sdf = new SimpleDateFormat[] {
     new SimpleDateFormat(/* format 1 */),
     new SimpleDateFormat(/* format 2 */),
     ...
  };

  ...

  Date date = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < sdf.length && date == null; i++) {
      try { 
          date = sdf[i].parse(dateString);
      } catch (ParseException ex) { /* */ }
  }
  if (date == null) {
      /* report parse error ... */
  }
```

But beware, you won't be able to handle every possible date format correctly.  For example, you won't be able to distinguish 7/6/2000 (English 7th of June 2000) from 7/6/2000 (American 6th of July 2000).

IMO, you are better off giving the user a Date chooser of some kind.

---

> ... but i want Dataformat is like this yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

The date format strings are documented in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `SimpleDateFormat`.  Read the documentation and you will be able to work it out.  And you will be able to work out how to parse other formats too!

Comment: please tell me Solution coz i really new in Android and Java

Comment: Date startdate = null; Date endatedate = null; SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); try { startdate = sdf.parse(Sdate); endatedate = sdf.parse(Edate); } catch (ParseException e) { throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse date: ", e); } i have parse but date is coming like this Sun May 29 20:16:00 IST 2016  @Stephen C

Comment: that is ok Dear but i want Dataformat is like this yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss please help me in this

Comment: Solution is to read the documentation ... and learn :-)